Why does the haftorah for Chanukah begin "rani visimchi ", and not "I saw a gold menorah"?
B"H
In the haftorah for Chanukah we begin the passage with "Rani visimcha bas Tzion", sing and rejoice, daughter of Tzion
Earlier in that same passage it says, "Behold, I saw a gold menorah..."
Seemingly it would have been more fitting to begin the haftorah with the verse that talks about the menorah, as the (main) miracle of Chanukah was about the oil in the menorah.
Why is the custom to skip that verse and start later in the passage?

The menorah is talked about in perek 4, which is after the Rani Visimcha, and we do read both of them

@CuriousYid who's we?

Never mind I thought you were talking about this weeks Parsha not chanukah

@Awtsmoos--עצמות can you clarify in your question which pesukim you are referring to… roni vesimchi is 2:14. As far as I can tell, the menorah comes afterwards, in 4:2.

There is a maamar from admur hazaken in Torah ohr that addresses this question.

@Menachem you refer to a maamar from admur hazaken*.By "admur hazaken", do you mean the first Lubavicher Rebbe often called theba'al HaTanya or the alter Rebbe?

@EdwardB yes, that’s right

@EdwardB haven't heard from you since sept, it's been a busy few months, just checking in on you - how was yom tov? All ok?

@RabbiKaii thanks for asking. Yes a bussy time over chagim and after. Hope to visit more regularly again now
